# Why does passing by reference fix my recursion error?

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I'm just starting to learn about recursion and I have a program that searches a vector of 5 ints for a value and returns the subscript location of the value. I noticed that when I pass the vector by value, I get an incorrect subscript location of like 72784658.

However, when I pass the vector by reference, changing nothing else, I get the correct answer. Can someone explain why? Below is the code where the vector is passed by value, which produces the incorrect answer.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int search( vector<int>, int, int );

int main() 
{
    vector<int> myInts;
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        myInts.push_back( i );

    cout << "The number 2 is at subsript " << search( myInts, 2, 0 ) << endl;

    return 0; 
}

int search( vector<int> vec, int val, int index )
{
    if( index < vec.size() )
    {
        if( vec[index] == val )
            return index;
        else
            search( vec, val, index + 1 );
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You recurse, but don't return the value of the recursive call:

```
search( vec, val, index + 1 );
// Should be this:
return search( vec, val, index + 1 );
```

This causes the end of the function to be reached without returning any particular value, so any result at all is possible, including no result. Flow reaching the end of a non-void function without encountering a `return` statement is undefined behavior, so it would be legal for the compiler to make your program crash at that point.

Changing `vec` to a reference could cause the `index` parameter to occupy a different CPU register, perhaps the one used to return a value back to the caller.  This could explain why it appears to work when you change `vec` to a reference, but upgrading your compiler, changing your compiler options, or using a different compiler could produce a completely different result.  So even when it works the way you want, it's just a lucky coincidence.

As a side note, always compile with all possible warnings enabled, and I would also suggest making all warnings errors (`-Wall -pedantic`).  With these options this code will not even compile.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why passing by reference fixes the issue?

Comment: @Mr.Llama It doesn't fix it. It just so happens that the undefined return value happens to be the one he wants with his particular compiler version and compile-time options.

Comment: @Mr.Llama OP has an UB, why to elaborate different aspects of UB, even if it looks like as a correct result by coincidence?

Comment: @Mr.Llama I guess it's because the compiler was smart enough to convert the recursion into an iteration in the pass by reference case. It can't do that when passing by value since it still has the destructor of the vector to call after the recursive call returns. The result is that in one case the correct return happens precisely at the stack location that is used for the return value of the uppermost `search` invocation, while in the other case that value is written to a stack frame that is some frames down. Anyway, anything could have happened, and the compiler should have warned about this.

Comment: (Using pass by reference) If it's a coincidence, then why does passing 0, 1, 3, and 4 to `search()` all return correct answers? And, for instance, filling the vector with a bunch of 0s and one 42, then searching for 42 returns the correct index. Surely that can't be coincidence? What's going on? Is cmaster correct in that the compiler is converting it to an iteration?

Comment: @nanny It could be using a tail call, which is one way that recursion can be converted to iteration. At the end of the day, the answer is that it's undefined behavior and therefore anything might happen. You can't reason about undefined behavior. You can speculate about it, but that's not very productive. And this would be a good example of compiler options changing the result -- if you use an optimization level that does not optimize recursion then you might see the original behavior.